# Install specific gcc version on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

I have a problem to install old version of gcc.
I want to install gcc with version 4.6.1 (not 4.6.4 or 4.7.x etc).
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.. Is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you mean install via a package manager then that is unlikely, unless you can find someone who has .debed this up for your type of machine (eg i386 or amd64), but you can download, configure and install any version gcc you like if your follow the instructions here - http://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Comment: That's so not simple. 
But thanks, I will try it. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean install via a package manager then that is unlikely, unless you can find someone who has .debed this up for your type of machine (eg i386 or amd64), but you can download, configure and install any version gcc you like if your follow the instructions here - [gcc.gnu.org/install](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/) – adrianmcmenamin